# Convert WebClient to XmlElement. VB.NET

Tags: xml, api, vb.net

I have link to API.XML and need to convert its data to XmlElement for further iteration

My solution is:

```
dim wc as WebClient = new WebClient()
wc.DownloadFile("http://192.168.88.11:8088/api", "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\getxml.xml")
dim doc as XmlDocument = new XmlDocument()
doc.Load("C:\Users\admin\Desktop\getxml.xml")
dim x as XmlElement = doc.DocumentElement
```

Is there more proper way without saving it to file?

Comment: Использовать `wc.DownloadString` и `doc.LoadXml`

Comment: Ошибка в 4-й строке: Невозможно преобразовать значение типа "System.Net.WebClient" в "String"

`
dim wc as WebClient = new WebClient()

wc.DownloadString("http://192.168.88.61:8088/api")

dim doc as XmlDocument = new XmlDocument()

doc.LoadXml(wc)
`

Comment: `DownloadString` **возвращает** строку.

Comment: а как её преобразовать в xml?

Comment: `dim xml as string = wc.DownloadString(...) ... doc.LoadXml(xml)`

Answer (score 0):

Решение оказалось проще

```
Dim x As New XmlDocument()
x.Load("http://192.168.88.61:8088/api")
```

Comment: Это простой способ, но он не всегда будет работать. Например, сервер можно требовать заголовки (http headers): user-agent, encoding и др.